# Why am I missing Hermite polynomial GSL functions [libgsl-dev]?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, c++

I installed GSL on ubntu 16.04 using:

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl2 libgsl-dev gsl-bin
```

The installed version is 2.1+dfsg-2 .  This works on some things but failed to calculate hermite polynomials.  The test code is:

```
// include files
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>  // gsl Bessel special function header 
file
//packages I need
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_gamma.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_hermite.h>

int
main (void)
{
  double x = 5.0;   // just a random test value

  double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);   // see the GSL manual for details

  cout << "J0(" << x << ") = "
       << setprecision(18) << setw(20) << y << endl;

  y = gsl_sf_hermite_phys(10,x);   // see the GSL manual for details
  cout << "H10(" << x << ") = "
       << setprecision(18) << setw(20) << y << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This does not compile with `g++ gsl_test.cpp -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm` .  The error is:

```
gsl_test.cpp:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to`gsl_sf_hermite_phys'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know "gsl_sf_hermite_phys" exists because I can use this on a system where I installed gsl manually.  If worst comes to worst I can just install gsl manually myself but I would like to be able to just use a terminal command to install and have a fully working and up to date GSL installation.

**Update: ** It turns out the gsl/gsl_sf_hermite.h header is not in 2.1+dfsg-2. I must have over-written an old install without realizing.

I guess my question is why are hermite polynomials not there and how to install GSL via terminal so that they are there.

Comment: I don't even see the *header* file `gsl/gsl_sf_hermite.h` in `libgsl-dev` version 2.1+dfsg-2 (although it is in 2.4+dfsg-6 - on my 17.10 box). Are you sure you don't have a manually-installed version of the header somewhere (which might explain why you don't have the corresponding library)?

Comment: Yes you are right, I guess this computer must have had a previous installation and I over-wrote it.  I installed it on a mint distro and you are right, no header file was found.   How did you install GSL on your system?

Comment: Same way as you - I think the message is that if you want `gsl_sf_hermite` functionality in a version that's installable via `apt`, then you will need to upgrade to at least Ubuntu 17.10 (or find a PPA that packages a newer GSL version for 16.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned `gsl/gsl_sf_hermite.h` header file is available in newer Ubuntu releases:

- [in 17.10 (artful)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=artful&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=gsl_sf_hermite.h)
- [in 18.04 LTS (development release)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=gsl_sf_hermite.h)